# Webpack default configuration object

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

From my understanding, **Webpack** is using `under the hood` a **default** configuration object which is different according to `development/production` environment. I am pretty sure about that, since it produces `different bundle results` for different environments without us specifying anything in `webpack.config.js`. However, I have the following queries:

- *Is it possible to see these default configuration objects?*
- *Is it possible to totally disable them?*
- *I think the only way to alter them is to override them by adding into our `webpack.config.js` the parts we want to change. Am I right?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Is it possible to see these default configuration objects?*

[Default Options here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/a0bfab2698753e3cce2ace066727c20f3bcd583a/lib/WebpackOptionsDefaulter.js)

*Is it possible to totally disable them?*

u can set `webpack --mode=none`

[More Info on mode here](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/)

*I think the only way to alter them is to override them by adding into our webpack.config.js the parts we want to change. Am I right?*

From Webpack medium blog

> With the new mode option we tried to reduce the required configuration
>   for a useful build. We tried to cover the common use cases with these
>   defaults.
>
> But from our experience we also know that defaults are not for
>   everyone. Each team has different needs, sometimes because of legacy
>   stuff, sometimes because of personal preferences, sometimes because of
>   special applications or sometimes because they don’t believe common
>   best practices. Many people do want to change defaults to adapt to own
>   use cases. We got you covered. Adding mode doesn’t mean that we remove
>   configuration. Everything is still configurable. We actually made most
>   of the internal optimization steps configurable (you can now disable
>   them).
>
> mode is implemented by setting default values to configuration
>   options. No special behavior is done by mode which isn’t possible via
>   other configuration option.

[Link to blog](https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-4-mode-and-optimization-5423a6bc597a)

Comment: About the first answer: Nice to provide this link. Is there a similar one for Webpack 3? Satisfied about the second answer. Still a bit confused about the third one. If not using `--mode none` or if using Webpack 3 any stuff in my webpack.config.js overrides the default settings?

Comment: @Unknowndeveloper  default mode is production, that means it will activate some additional plugins.

Comment: Yes, I think it should override the default settings.

Comment: @Unknowndeveloper, if my answer helped u, please accept it